# Excel VB Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use `VLOOKUP`, but with a variable for the column offset. For example: `=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'Sheet2'!C[-14],1,FALSE)` I want to replace the `-14` with a named variable.
Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1):

You might use the OFFSET worksheet function, as in something like: `=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],OFFSET(Sheet2!C,0,YourNamedVariable),1,FALSE)`

Comment: That does not seem to work either. Im thinking it's the type of formula Im trying to use here that is causing the problem. Here is more detail. This is the entire line of my code: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-41],'call number history'!C[-52],1,FALSE)"

Comment: ooops, hit ruturn. That "ActiveCell" is on Sheet1, the formula works as you see it written here. But I need to be able to have that value (-52) be a variable. Changing the formula to include OFFSET, or any other function, still will not accept reference to a variable.

Comment: Is the value of the variable fixed at the time that you set the FormulaR1C1 property, or could it change afterwards?

If it's fixed (and say, stored in a VBA variable named X), you could simply use something like: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-41],'call number history'!C[" & X & "],1,FALSE)"`.

Otherwise, you would need to use something like my first suggestion, where you would substitute `YourNamedVariable` with: a) a named range in Excel, b) a user-defined function, c) a cell reference, or, d) any other Excel expression that evaluated to the desired number.

Comment: Brian, my friend, Thank You. C[" & X & "] is exactly what it needed.

Comment: Your help is very much appreciated! Take care.